# AJAX POST : Not able to retrieve posted data array in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

> "company=1&cat=3&cat=1"

My Javascript object **"cat"** has two values 1 and 3 and now I want to post it to the server using AJAX. I am able to post the data and I can see data appearing in the PHP side but my problem is when I capture posted data in PHP it is only showing one value of **cat**.

actual data:

```
company = 1
```

but

```
cat = [1, 3];
```

here is my posted query:

**company=1&cat=3**

this is what PHP `print_r`  is showing:

```
 Array
(
    ["company] => 1
    [cat] => 3
    "
)
```

As you can see, the cat value is only one value instead of the array (1,3).

What am I missing here?

My ajax code

```
var datas= $.param(data, true);

    $.ajax({
            url: "/compcats/add",
            type: 'POST',

            data:  datas,
            success: function(res) {
            }

        });
```

Comment: You might make your life simpler by posting the whole thing as a json object in a single variable ... `{"Data": datas}`. Then on the PHP side, you can get the lot by doing `MyData = json_decode($_REQUEST['Data']);` That allows you to avoid the quirks around arrays in form encoding

Comment: If you call this in your browser as url, you would get the exact same result. you rewrite  `cat=3` wth `cat=1`

Answer (score 2):

Send cat parameter as array like this

```
"company=1&cat[0]=3&cat[1]=1"
```

Then in your PHP receive it as

```
$_POST["cat"][0]  ;    //output => 3
$_POST["cat"][1]  ;    //output => 1
```

Comment: so i have to do it manually and is it not possible with $.params()??

Comment: What is cat in your case.. are these checkbox ??

Comment: var datas= {
  company:1,
  cat: [ 3, 1 ]
};
 try in this way.

Answer (score 0):

you need to call your url like

```
company=1&cat[]=3&cat[]=1
```

call it in PHP like that:

```
$_GET["cat"][0];
```

or

```
$_REQUEST["cat"][0];
```

Comment: I tried to encode object to post it as query using $.params() , is it not right way ??

Comment: $.param() is serialization for arrays/objects. you dont need this for GET/POST-Requests, since PHP has a built in function for that special object. You can use it with $_REQUEST, $_GET and $_POST. No $.param needed here, this would only be needed for nested arrays.

Comment: you talk about jquery as sender, but the receiver surely is NOT jquery. you dont need $.param() for sending data, you can just send it the old way i mentioned in the answer. It just that your syntax was wrong.

Comment: and that's why? Using POST, GET or REQUEST does not take the responsibility from you to actually test and check your variables.

Comment: Martijn tries to tell you stop giving examples with them, because people that do not know better will use them. There is no reason why you cannot give examples using filter_input_array directly.

Comment: are you serious? that would be a common example of bad teaching. overload your answers and they just get ignored.